# HttpWebRequest, uploading a file

Tags: c#, file-upload, httpwebrequest

I hope someone can help me out. I have the following code, which is attempting to upload a file to the server using a HTTPWebRequest. I simply can't get it to work, resulting in the generic "HTTP Error 500 Internal server" error.

I have tried different iterations, splitting out the code into separate methods etc, but this is the simplest form of the code. I have searched high and low but cannot spot what I'm doing wrong!

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    public HttpWebResponse SubmitPOSTRequest(string url, Dictionary<string, object> postData = null, string fileName = "")
    {
        byte[] boundaryBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + this.FormDataBoundary + "\r\n"); 

        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + this.FormDataBoundary;
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)";
        wr.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        wr.Timeout = 600000;

        using (Stream stream = wr.GetRequestStream())
        {
            if (postData != null)
            {
                string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";

                // Loop through for non-file form-data.
                foreach (string key in postData.Keys)
                {
                    stream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);

                    string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, postData[key]);
                    byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);

                    stream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
            {
                stream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);

                string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
                string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "File", fileName, GetContentType(fileName));
                byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

                stream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = 0;

                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                fileStream.Close();
            }

            byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + this.FormDataBoundary + "--\r\n");
            stream.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);;
        }

        return wr.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
```

Comment: There isn't any simple&single rule to upload a file. The problem with those type of questions is that we don't know the **url**, and can't say anything about what your server expects....

Comment: why don't you give the [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile(v=vs.110).aspx) a chance instead of implementing http multipart ?

Comment: Thanks @OguzOzgul, using [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile(v=vs.110).aspx) was the simplest solution, removing much of the complicity of [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx). Thanks again